# Not able to create a Maven Project. I am using eclipse photon

Tags: maven

Error thrown is

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

I have checked maven installation using cmd and it shows there. I think some issue with pom.xml or settings.xml is there but not sure. I am new to Maven.

Comment: Also i have tried deleting all folders in .m2 folders and then force updating the project but it didn't work. I think main issue is with pom.xml and settings.xml. Please provide detailed answer

Comment: Most of these issues stem from a network problem: Eclipse is not able to contact MavenCentral because of some proxy or firewall setting.

Comment: Can you explain if there is a way to rectify this problem? I think the same that issue is with proxy server. But my settings.xml already has a proxy tag.